# Scraping with rvest not working properly

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest

I want to scrape the second main table on this page: https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/f/forsbfi01.html, the "NHL Possession Metrics" table. Rvest should allow me to do this easily:

```
fil_link <- "https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/f/forsbfi01.html"

fil_pos <- fil_link %>% 
 read_html %>% 
 html_node(css = "#skaters_advanced") %>% 
 html_table(header = T)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class 
  "xml_missing"
```

I got the first table with essentially the same code, while swapping out the css code. Plus, I've looked around the table code, checking to make sure I get the actual table selector, and not the container, innards, etc. Why won't this scrape?

Comment: Modern web pages aren't very scrape-able because most use javascript to populate a page and rvest can't execute JavaScript. In this case that particular webpage happens to also include a plain table in a comment block. Be sure to google "scrape" and the URL for the website you are trying to scrape first because every website might require a different trick and solutions are already posted for many sites.

Comment: That particular table's html code is not formatted as an html table, however contradictory this might sound. rvest html_table will not be able to parse it as a matrix. You might need to extract each element and parse it through a custom function.

Comment: Ah. I see. Thank you

Comment: papelr, ask it again. I found a custom solution. @MrFlick marked this question as a duplicate, which I would dispute because your are asking to parse a  table/html structure that is not equivalent to the one present in the alleged duplicate.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez It may be technicality a different table on the page, but extracting the data is going to require the same technique. Do we really need a SO post on how to scrape every table on every web page? I'll re-open the question if you can give some indication of how this is different. The table seems to be in a comment just like the other question.

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez OK. It's reopen. Feel free to add your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve the problem for this particular table.
But please note that it is a very fragile solution. It assumes a matrix structure of only 3 rows, and expects all rows to have the same number of elements.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

## Create a function to parse every row in the table.
Hockey_table <- function(htmlObject) { 

  titlerow <- htmlObject %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="stats_pullout"]/div/div/h4') %>%  html_text('data-tip')
  firstrow <- htmlObject %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="stats_pullout"]/div/div/p[1]') %>% html_text()
  secondrow <- htmlObject %>% html_nodes(xpath = '//div[@class="stats_pullout"]/div/div/p[2]') %>% html_text()

  data.frame(titlerow, firstrow, secondrow)
```

}

```
 Page01 <- read_html('https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/f/forsbfi01.html')
Hockey_table(Page01)
```

Results:

```
   titlerow firstrow secondrow
 1   SUMMARY  2017-18    Career
 2        GP       67       331
 3         G       26       117
 4         A       38       138
 5       PTS       64       255
 6       +/-       27        26
 7        PS      8.3      32.1
 8       PIM       38       145
 9        SH      179       931
 10      GWG        6        24
 11      TOI    17:28     17:49
 12      CF%     53.0      54.9
 13     oZS%     54.1      63.4
```

Comment: I see the fragility. I appreciate the workaround, thank you!